# How to make a list of time day in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, calendar, schedule

How can I make a schedule list, just like the picture? I tried to search, but I found nothing on the web.

It would be like this

[image: 1]

To be more specific, the schedule list is fixed and not editable, next to it you can write!

Gif of Demonstration

[image: 2]

Answer (score 0):

the best way is to read about the class [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=net-5.0) and [DateTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.addhours?view=net-5.0), with an instance of that class init to Janeiro 1st at 7:00AM you can simple add 1 hour and print it...

here is a mini example how... (pretty similar to the documentation in the link i posted.)

```
using System;

public class Test
{
   public static void Main()
   {
       DateTime dateValue = new DateTime(2021, 1, 31, 7, 0, 0);

      for(int i = 0; i<14; ++i)
         Console.WriteLine(dateValue.AddHours(i));
   }
}
```

Output:

> 1/31/2021 7:00:00 AM
>
> 1/31/2021 8:00:00 AM
>
> 1/31/2021 9:00:00 AM
>
> 1/31/2021 10:00:00 AM
>
> 1/31/2021 11:00:00 AM
>
> 1/31/2021 12:00:00 PM
>
> 1/31/2021 1:00:00 PM
>
> etc etc

now if you really need

13:00 instead of 1:00 PM then read too this link about you to represent (format) a date to a desired string:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo?view=net-5.0

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I want! I already edited the post to be more specific!